# Как правильно подключить jquery для wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

[Сайт](http://new.gradk.site/)

На момент верстки в jquery был подключен в футере и слик слайдер работал корректно:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Но уже при посадке веркте на wordpress все подключения реализовал так и слайдер сломался:

jquery согласно документации в functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
function my_scripts_method() {
    // отменяем зарегистрированный jQuery
    wp_deregister_script('jquery-core');
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');

    // регистрируем
    wp_register_script( 'jquery-core', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js', false, null, true );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', false, array('jquery-core'), null, true );

    // подключаем
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
```

А скрипты тоже в functions, но с выводом в футере:

```
if(!is_admin()) { 
wp_enqueue_script('slick', get_template_directory_uri() . '/plugins/slick/slick.min.js', 'jquery', null, true);
wp_enqueue_script('script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', 'script', null, true);
wp_enqueue_script('script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js', 'jquery_ui', null, true);
}
```

Как правильно подключить jquery чтобы корректно работал слайдер?

Comment: Только заметил, что теперь jquery подключился в футере ниже моих скриптов, как задать ему приоритет, чтобы подключение в футере занимало самое высокое место?

Comment: Константин, а Вы отчаянный... Взять натяжку верстки на WooCommerce не имея базовых понятий по подключению скриптов и стилей. Начинайте с блогов, Вы не осилите Woo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Последний параметр в wp_enqueue_script отвечает за подключение в футер. У Вас он установлен в true, соответственно jQuery подключается в футер. А вообще если делать в футере подключение то у вас зависимости указаны не правильно, они должны быть в массиве array('jquery'). И у jquery-ui и script заданы одинаковые имена скриптов ( первый параметр)

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
function my_scripts_method() {
// отменяем зарегистрированный jQuery
wp_deregister_script('jquery-core');
wp_deregister_script('jquery');

// регистрируем
  wp_register_script( 'jquery-core', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js', false, null, true );
  wp_register_script( 'jquery', false, array('jquery-core'), null, true );

  // подключаем
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

  if(!is_admin()) { 
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery_ui', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('slick', get_template_directory_uri() . '/plugins/slick/slick.min.js', array('jquery-ui'), null, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array('slick'), null, true);
  }
}
```